# groupBy in Select2 output

Tags: ajax, laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-query-builder

I'm using Select2 for dynamic drop-down search with Ajax, same "type" (column name) is not grouping.

[image: type]

Tried to group similar column using groupBy() but its retrieving only first row.

[image: sametype]

As you can see above it's fetching all data perfectly but not grouping.

Controller:

```
 $data = DB::table('vehitrans')
                ->select("id", "name", "type")
                ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$search%")->orWhere('type','LIKE', "%$search%")
                ->groupBy('type')
                ->get();
```

Ajax:

```
 processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.type,
                        children: [{
                         text: item.name,
                         id:item.id,
                        }]
                    }
                })
            }
          }
```

I want all "name" should come under its respective "type" 
eg.

```
Vehicles
   Car
   Tractor
```

Comment: What you get if you search for "vehicles"?

Comment: Same result, getting first row only [link](https://gph.is/g/E3g9QpY)

Comment: Have you checked if the problem is in the DB query or in how you are populating the select? you can make a `dd($data);` to see what the query returns to be sure that the problem is there

Comment: In network response tab it returning only first row when searching by "vehicle" [{id: 1, name: "Car", type: "Vehicles", created_at: null, updated_at: null}], don't know the reason

Comment: Tried both, same result :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198841/discussion-between-glitchy-and-porloscerros-).